# Azure Functions Powershell: module could not be loaded via managed dependencies

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

We are having trouble importing a library form powershellgallery.com: [IntuneWin32App](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IntuneWin32App/1.2.1).
The error msg goes as follows:

```
"ERROR: The 'New-IntuneWin32AppPackage' command was found in the module 'IntuneWin32App', but the module could not be loaded."
```

We are running Azure functions 3, Powershell 7.1.
IntuneWin32App is imported via managed dependencies. Specified in the "requirements.psd1" as follows:

```
'IntuneWin32App' = '1.*'
```

We have tried several solutions for related issues to this error but none could help us.

EDIT: detailed output: https://pastebin.com/t3kBF00A

We also did a deployment of the function to the cloud environment and we are retrieving the same issue over there.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in 7.2.0-preview.7 or 5.1. Are you able to test/capture output of  Import-Module Intunewin32App -Force -Verbose ?

Comment: Please note that Azure Functions is currently using PowerShell 7.0.6. In order to diagnose the issue, I would recommend installing PowerShell 7.0.6 locally and running the Import-Module command that Doug provided: the error message will have the details.

Comment: Hi @DougMaurer, please look at this pastebin for the full output: https://pastebin.com/t3kBF00A

Comment: HI @AnatoliBeliaev, look at my comment above for the full output. I did not yet swap to PS 7.0.6 locally because i tested my function in the cloud environment and i am getting the same error over there. Let me know if you still think this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[2021-07-30T06:54:54.792Z] ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Does the module require authentication? It seems it's trying to launch a winforms window which isn't available in PowerShell 7.

Is there another authentication mechanism you can use with that module like service principal or certificate that prevents the window?

Comment: Hi @BrettMiller, there are certain functions in the module that require delegated authentication (username / password), for connection to MS Graph API. The function that i am calling in my code does not require connection to MS Graph API.

Comment: You could branch out to windows PowerShell on the underlying functions host. `Import-Module <ModuleName> -UseWindowsPowerShell`. The error is clearly related to winforms which is not available in v7. The module you're using states that only basic Auth works. https://github.com/MSEndpointMgr/IntuneWin32App#authentication so no way for it to work as of yet by the look of things.